# Have two users collaborate in a directory

Tags: permissions, groups

Can anyone help me to solve this.its simple.but i have full of doubts.

Create a directory on /mnt/data. 2 users there, Alice and Bob, and both of them are in group admins. Both of the users collaboratively work on this directory, and also file and directory created in this directory should automatically belongs to group admins. All members of the group have `rw` access. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: This (AskUbuntu) isn't a "do my homework" site.

Comment: Git or some other source control system is the only solution. Two (or more) people working on the same files with no means to audit? That’s a fail in 2013, let alone the current year. Systems need to be auditable. This doesn’t mean “being able to blame”, but “being able to understand” 

Answer (score 1):

Your `umask` needs to be set so files by default have permissions for groups to read, write and execute. The default `umask`  on Ubuntu, `0002` is adequate.

You then set the `setgid` bit so files and directories that are created in the shared directory will automatically be assigned the common group (`admins` in your example).

1. Make sure the shared directory is owned by the group `admin`
2. Set the `setgid` bit: `chmod g+s /mnt/data`